# Python dataframe counting occurences over specific number of previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, counter

I have a dataframe with a few 100 ids that I want to iterate over. I want to iterate over them such that I compare the value in one column to only 30 of the previous values in that dataframe (monthly data). I want to count the occurences of the value at hand with the previous 30 rows. Can someone please help me with this?

If the dataframe index = 0 or some number less than 30, I have to look up data values from another dataframe (of an earlier month) so that I am always comparing with 30 values before the value I have.

I have been trying to slice and use pd.concat with my data but it has not been working.

```
count = 0 
for i in df_current.index:
    val = df_current['id'].index
    df_current = df_current[0:i]
    df_previous = df_previous[i:]
    new_df = pd.concat([df_previous, df_current])
    if(len(new_df[new_df['id'] == val]) != 0):
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to count how many occurrences in a previous window. I've set my window to 5 instead of 30, and I don't have your other dataframe to look up previous values, so the indices without enough previous elements have a count of null.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':np.random.randint(low=1,high=5,size=20),
})


df['id_count'] = df['id'].rolling(5).apply(lambda v: sum(v == v.iloc[-1])-1)
df
```

The output is

[image: output]